# How to create framework / library for iOS in Swift, to be used in other projects?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, sdk

We created an iOS application which does map functionalities(used MAPKIT) and filters of the locations. We need to convert it into ios SDK. Is that possible?

Comment: iOS sdk ? I think you mean iOS Library

Comment: Yes you can always separate your re-usable components and ship it as a framework. Might help: https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/getting-started-with-reusable-frameworks-for-ios-development-f00d74827d11

Comment: Check this question its same as u asked [How to create SDK for iOS in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46127937/how-to-create-sdk-for-ios-in-swift).

Comment: Yes, its framework  not SDK!

Comment: It is possible, but try to consider if you want a Framework or a Static Library. Both have advantages and shortcomings. The most important one in your case might be that Static libraries can't contain resources (Images, String files, etc.). There are ways to add them but it's kind of hard.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make re-usable libraries / framework to be used if different project of yours. 
Following are the steps :

1. In Xcode, select **File ▸ New ▸ Project….**
2. Choose **iOS ▸ Framework & Library ▸ Cocoa Touch Framework.**
   [image]
3. Click **Next.**
4. Set the **Product Name**, Use your own **Organization Name** and **Organization Identifier**.
   [image]
5. Click **Next.**
6. In the file chooser, choose to create the project at the some level as of **YourProjects** root folder.
7. Click **Create**.

Your current state is a framework without code, add relevant code to your newly made framework and build the framework project to make sure that you get Build Succeeded with no build warnings or errors.

A complete step-by-step demo can be found at link :
[Creating a Framework for iOS](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5109-creating-a-framework-for-ios)

Comment: Please avoid link only answers.

Comment: @GoodSp33d - Why should I re-write the steps which is already well documented with good example on some reputed site.

Comment: From [answer]: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: @MartinR - thanks for the advice, that make sense. I will update this answer as per your advice.